# Can a received DatagramPacket be used to be sent again?

Tags: java, echo, datagram

I am testing a UDP echo server, is the following code correct?

```
DatagramSocket s = ...
DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(new byte[512], 512);

...

s.recieve(p);
s.send(p);
```

My question is, can I send the `DatagramPacket` just as I recieved it? According to the java specification, the contructor I used constructs a DatagramPacket 'for recieving use'. I am not sure if that state changes when the packet has been modified through `s.recieve`, or if that 'for recieve use state' is permanent.

If the code is correct, is there any reason why in the tutorial they construct a whole new `DatagramPacket`? (maybe just clarity?)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html

Comment: I don't see (and never have seen) in Java any `DatagramPacket` ctor that uses `char[]`. Like all other Java socket I/O and low-level file I/O (that is, `Stream` rather than `Reader` and `Writer`) *and* the tutortial you point to, it always uses `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and it's quite common. If you receive a request, the DatagramPacket already has the return address in it, so all you need to do is put the response data into it and send it back.